# Display dialogs in a loop and act on the accept event

Tags: javascript, nativescript

In my Nativescript app I have a loop and want to display a dialog for each item being iterated over. When the dialog displays it contains "Accept" and  "Reject" options, both of which when clicked I would like to call a method which I pass the iterated item into. The issue is since the option selection returns a promise I lose the reference to the iterated item. What can I do to get around this? Here's an example of my code.

EDIT: I also really don't like that I'm declaring a function in the loop after the promise returns.

```
function _showPendingConnections() {    
    for (var i = 0; i < ViewModel.pendingConnections.length; i++) {
        var pendingConnection = ViewModel.pendingConnections[i];
        dialog.confirm({
            message: pendingConnection.PatientFirstName + " would like to share their glucose readings with you.",
            okButtonText:"Accept",
            cancelButtonText:"Reject"                                    
        }).then(function(result) {
            if(result === true) {
                ViewModel.acceptConnection(pendingConnection);
            } else {
                ViewModel.removeConnection(pendingConnection);
            }            
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change worked for me (I have probably created different viewModel but however the idea is the same) - all I have done is to change when your item index is passed.

For example:

```
// main-page.js

"use strict";
var main_view_model_1 = require("./main-view-model");
var dialogModule = require("ui/dialogs");
var viewModel = new main_view_model_1.MyViewModel();
viewModel.pendingConnections = [{ PatientFirstName: "John" }, { PatientFirstName: "Merry" }, { PatientFirstName: "Abygeil" }];
// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
function navigatingTo(args) {
    // Get the event sender
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;
    for (var index = viewModel.pendingConnections.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        connectionDealer(index);
    }
}
exports.navigatingTo = navigatingTo;
function connectionDealer(index) {
    var pendingConnection = viewModel.pendingConnections[index];
    dialogModule.confirm({
        message: pendingConnection["PatientFirstName"] + " would like to share their glucose readings with you.",
        okButtonText: "Accept",
        cancelButtonText: "Reject"
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result === true) {
            // your code follow.. pass pendingConnection[index] to your method
            console.log("accepted by " + pendingConnection["PatientFirstName"]);
        }
        else {
            // your code follow.. pass pendingConnection[index] to your method
            console.log("Rejected by " + pendingConnection["PatientFirstName"]);
        }
    });
}


// main-view-model.js

   "use strict";
var observable = require("data/observable");
var MyViewModel = (function (_super) {
    __extends(MyViewModel, _super);
    function MyViewModel() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Object.defineProperty(MyViewModel.prototype, "pendingConnections", {
        get: function () {
            return this._pendingConnections;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            if (this._pendingConnections !== value) {
                this._pendingConnections = value;
            }
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return MyViewModel;
}(observable.Observable));
exports.MyViewModel = MyViewModel;
```

Comment: In my case I'm using vanilla Javascript over Typescript. would the Get and Set notation in the view-model be the same?

Comment: I have changed the sample to vanilla JavaScript code